# traduction gettext with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gettext

I 'm from peru present .
what happens is that eh followed a tutorial on gettext and CodeIgniter and I can not get it to work , I only translates the text into Spanish peru .
the only thing that changed was the helper eh , that after writing the function , execute it as follows . set_translation_language ( en_EU ) , or where I have to run this function . ?
From already thank you very much.

Comment: This is the tutorial forgiveness :

http://uno-de-piera.com/webs-multi-idioma-con-gettext-en-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at this: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/language.html
CodeIgniter already support multi-language (location).

If your site will support only one language (Spanish), there is no need to use a location service.

But if you plan to support English and Spanish for example, what you need to do is:

- Create a folder with the language name (ie: English)
- Add a file with `"_lang.php"` (no quotes) at the end (ie: `text_lang.php`)
- Create an array under the value `$lang`, each object inside will contain the
  key, for example: `$lang['title'] = "This is the title.";` (English)
  and then on the Spanish folder, the same but translated:
  `$lang['title'] = "Este es el título.";`
- Load the language file: `$this->lang->load('text_lang', 'spanish');` that's valid in our example.
- Last, but not least, load the language line you want to translate, for example, title `$this->lang->line('title');`